# SQL Server : how to know which stored procedure called a function in real time

Tags: function, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to know which procedure called, in real time, my function.

I need to store a log every time that my functions is called, and in that log I need to know the name of the stored procedure that called it.

I found this:

```
select 
    so.name 'Object Name', so2.name 'Dependent On', sd.*
from 
    sys.sysdepends sd
join 
    sys.objects so on so.object_id = sd.id
join 
    sys.objects so2 on so2.object_id = sd.depid
where 
    so2.name = 'FUNCTION_NAME'
```

But, this code returns the dependencies, I mean, all the stored procedures that were compiled calling the function BUT what I really need to know it the procedure that is actually, in that particular call, calling the function so I can store it in a log table.

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for functionality that doesn't exist. Besides which, if you're inside a UDF, you're not allowed to change the database state, so logging isn't going to be possible anyway.

Comment: Why am I needing this?. I have a functions that's really old and I have a los of procedures that are compiled with the call of this function in them BUT not all of them are workng, I mean, a lot of those SPs are obsolete. Hence, I need to know what SPs are really calling the funciont

Comment: If you don't know which SPs are being executed, how will you know when you've done "enough" logging to identify all callers. E.g., hypothetically, there could be something, somewhere, that ends up calling this function on the 1st April, every 5 years.

Comment: You are right, that's why I wanted to leave the log for a week. Ok, but  Damien_The_Unbeliever says that this functionality doesn't exists.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It does not exist directly in t-sql, but the SQL Profiler tool (part of sql server) does exactly what he wants.

Comment: As does XEvents, with is the replacement for SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Profiler tool is able to create such a log. It's part of the sql server package. Just set it up such that it logs everything, then let it run for a week.

Comment: Doing that on a busy production server could well cause a lot of issues.

Comment: @MartinSmith Not necessarily. We did so to track down performance problems with a specific procedure which is called very often, and we had absolutely no delays. Besides, you can restrict the profiler to protocol only function and procedure calls. Also, you can filter out some procedures which are called very often.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events, filtering on the object name/id.  With those two tools, you should also be able to determine the caller of the object.  You also have the ability to save the results to a file or table, so you can start the trace and turn it off at will.